# how to mapping multiple ngram analyzers elasticsearch, logstash

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to register multiple analyzers in one column.

If the keyword is one letter, I want to apply uni-gram,
if it is two letters, it is bi-gram,
and if it is three letters, I want to apply tri-gram.

Below are my settings.

```json
{
    "template":"*",
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
              "tokenizers": ["my_tokenizer", "my_tokenizer2", "my_tokenizer3"]
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "my_tokenizer": {
              "type": "ngram",
              "min_gram": 1,
              "max_gram": 1,
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ]
            }, "my_tokenizer2": {
              "type": "ngram",
              "min_gram": 2,
              "max_gram": 2,
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ]
            },
            "my_tokenizer3": {
              "type": "ngram",
              "min_gram": 3,
              "max_gram": 3,
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "type":"date"
            },
            "name":{
                "type":"text",
                "fields":{
                    "ngram":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
                    }   
                }
                
            },
            "name2":{
                "type":"text",
                "fields":{
                    "ngram":{
                        "type":"text",
                        "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
                    }   
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```json
input{
   jdbc{
      jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/kun/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29/mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar"
      jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbtest"
      jdbc_user => "xxxx"
      jdbc_password => "xxxx"
      tracking_column => "unix_ts_in_secs_user"
      use_column_value => true
      tracking_column_type => "numeric"
      schedule => "*/3 * * * * *"
      statement => "SELECT *,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updatedAt) as unix_ts_in_secs_user
       FROM user WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updatedAt) > :sql_last_value AND updatedAt < NOW())"
      last_run_metadata_path => "./logstash_jdbc_last_run_user"
      type => "user"
   }
}

filter{
   mutate {
      add_field => {
         "pkid" => "%{id}_%{type}"
      }
   }
}

output{
   

   if [type] == "user" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
            index => "index_user_test10"
            user=>"xxxx"
            password=>"xxxx"
            document_id => "%{pkid}"

            template=> "/Users/kun/Downloads/test_template.json"
            template_name=>"user_test-10"
        }
    }
   
}
```

I want to connect the corresponding `ngram-tokenizer` to name1 and name2 in the user table, respectively.

However, if you run the above code, only `my_analyzer` is connected.

Should I create multiple indexes on the same table and apply the analyzer separately?

I would like to select and use one of several `my_analyzers` based on search keyword`s length.

How can I use it?

Thank you

---

Additional question) I changed the conf file, deleted the index and created a new one. But the change doesn't seem to take effect. I don't know why it doesn't change.

When inputting directly through kibana, both _setting and _mapping work.

Comment: fyi there's no such thing as tables or columns in Elasticsearch. it's an index or indexes/indices. and then documents with fields and values

Comment: the first thing I can notice is that you probably need to change the values of the `name.ngram` fields, as they are all the same

Comment: @MarkWalkom thank you! I'll try changing the name of name.ngrams!

Comment: @MarkWalkom Changed my code, generated additional question!

Comment: @KunAguero what error you are getting? can you add that to your question

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast No error message is displayed. The `template` created at the beginning is applied, and changes are not applied.

Comment: @KunAguero how you know changes are not applied? can you provide the O/p of `_settings` api?

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast I don't know what `O/p` is. Previously, there was only one `my_tokenizer`, min_gram :1 max_gram:2. I changed the conf file like the code in the question, but only my_tokenizer min:1,max:2 are created.

Comment: @KunAguero o/p is for output, can you provide the output of your index settings ?

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast I added new code!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246876/discussion-between-amit-es-enthusiast-and-kunaguero).